# Is mixed content blocking exclusive of Google Ads?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a site that uses Google Ads. I don't think I'm doing anything different or unusual, I'm just including the code Google Adsense gave me in my static HTML pages.

However, today I loaded my website and noticed my Google Ads weren't there. I opened Firebug, and I saw this error:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"
```

I found a [Mozilla blog post explaining what mixed content blocking is](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/). According to this blog post, this has been a feature since version 23, though I've only updated to version 24 yesterday and noticed my Google Ads not working today.

Although the blog's explanation goes over my head, I think I grasp that mixed content blocking is something to do with potential dangers from pulling content from many different sources. In this case, my Google Ads are coming from a third party, namely Google.

But, this seems a little excessive. Is having a Google Ad really a big security exception?

In any case, is there something I can do to ensure that my Google Ads show, even in a Firefox browser?

Comment: Can you add the code (that includes Google Ads to your pages) to the question?

Comment: @MrLister: Nice. That was the solution. All I had to do was change where I called `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js` to `https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js` and it worked. If you make an answer out of what you suggested, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by mixing content with different protocols, i.e. http and https.

https is secure, while http is not. So if you have a page that is called with `https://domain.com` and it uses a file `http://domain.com/filename` the latter is non-secure!

Solution: either use https or http for everything throughout your site. Don't mix them.